# Are `;;` required to close "all" case sections in bash?

Tags: bash

I've seen case statements without the `;;` after a clause, but only when there was a single case.  For example, something like this:

```sh
case $val in
  ($glob) echo "the glob matched the val"
esac
```

But, maybe this is bad form?  Or has a consequence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`;;` is optional after the last case before `esac`. It's good form to put it in, because it's easily forgotten when you decide later to rearrange the order of the cases, or add a new one at the end.